# Animation Nodes addon / There is a Python version mismatch

Tags: python, add-on

I'm a total noob, what do I do to install Animation nodes?

I remember installing python, do I uninstall it?

[image]

Comment: You must use Blender Version 3.1 + or a previous Animation Nodes release

Comment: To your second question: You don't need to uninstall any versions of Python you installed yourself.  Blender uses its own copy of Python.  You just need to update to a newer version of Blender or find an older version of animation nodes on github as @Gorgious said