# Animation node values not updated on render animation. MWE steps included

Tags: video-sequence-editor, animation-nodes

## Issue

Render with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> always shows the value in timeline at the time of render (`10.0`), but want current frame number. How can I fix number shown in animation render (important: must not be static render) to be frame number?

Seeking in timeline with `Sequencer and Preview` works fine.

All frames of render are:

[image: render]

but want `1.0` for frame #1, `2.0` for frame #2, and so on.

## Attempted solve

- Nodes: `Overview` --> `Bake to Keyframes`
- Use older animation nodes: [Python version mismatch](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/264417/50044)

## Setup

### VSE

- Add text strip

[image: vse]

### Animation nodes

- Add nodes and connect: `Time Info:Frame` --> `Data:Convert to Text:Text` --> `Text:Text Sequence Output`

[image: nodes]

## Environment

- Blender: latest ([3.4.1 for Linux](https://www.blender.org/download/release/Blender3.4/blender-3.4.1-linux-x64.tar.xz/))
- Animation nodes: latest ([`animation_nodes_v2_3_linux_py310.zip`](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases/download/master-cd-build/animation_nodes_v2_3_linux_py310.zip))

## References

Based on https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73975

Comment: looks like a bug to me. Maybe open an issue on github/animationnodes?